# (LuaLaTeX) Why does text width between the same phrase in different sentences seem to be inconsistent when comparing these two examples?

Tags: spacing, babel, microtype, cyrillic, russian

I have these two examples of text that have both Cyrillic and Latin in them. It is for a personal thing I am working on, but I didn't realise that there was a bitnof an inconsistent feature with the width when typing out the same beginning phrase in both sentences

**The following code uses Times New Roman .ttf files from Windows, it should load with no problem for Windows users using a local TeX editor.**

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % loads fontspec
   \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, BoldFont=Timesbd.ttf, ItalicFont=Timesi.ttf, BoldItalicFont=Timesbi.ttf]{Times.ttf}
\usepackage[main=english, russian]{babel} % english is using american english 
    \babelposthyphenation{russian}{ |[{0300}-{036F}] }{ remove, {} }


\begin{document}

When the unstressed vowels come at the end (\foreignlanguage{russian}{Б\'ыло}), beginning (\foreignlanguage{russian}{Алб\'анка}), or right before the stress (\foreignlanguage{russian}{Пот\'ом}), they sound like Spanish 'A'.

When the unstressed О and А appear two or more syllables before the stress (\foreignlanguage{russian}{Хорош\'о}), or after the stress (\foreignlanguage{russian}{С\'орок}) (but not at the end of the word), it will sound like english 'uh'

\end{document}
```

**If not on Windows/on an online editor, please use this code**

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % loads fontspec
   \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[main=english, russian]{babel} % english is using american english 
    \babelposthyphenation{russian}{ |[{0300}-{036F}] }{ remove, {} }


\begin{document}

When the unstressed vowels come at the end (\foreignlanguage{russian}{Б\'ыло}), beginning (\foreignlanguage{russian}{Алб\'анка}), or right before the stress (\foreignlanguage{russian}{Пот\'ом}), they sound like Spanish 'A'.

When the unstressed О and А appear two or more syllables before the stress (\foreignlanguage{russian}{Хорош\'о}), or after the stress (\foreignlanguage{russian}{С\'орок}) (but not at the end of the word), it will sound like english 'uh'

\end{document}
```

Picture: [image]

The beginning phrase "When the unstressed" is different widths in the two sentences. Is this supposed to be the case? Is there perhaps something done wrong in my code? I am not entirely sure why this is the case. If someone could please help me with this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, this is in order. The lines require different amount of stretch/shrink.

Comment: how else would you get a justified right margin?

Comment: If you insist on an identical look of the first three words in these two paragraphs, you can put them in an `\hbox`: `\indent\hbox{When the unstressed} vowels...`.

Answer (score 2):

by default tex justifies paragraphs. That is, arrange the right edge of the text block to be straight by adjusting inter word space and with microtype also making small adjustments to letter shapes.

So it is almost always the case that a phrase occuring on two different lines will have different widths.

If you use `\ragedright` then justification is disabled and inter word spaces will all be their natural width.